# Find a expansion to a orthonormalbasis v1,v2,v3,v4

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V = $\mathbb{R^4}$ with standard scalar product and let

$v_1 :=\left( \dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2} \right)$,
$v_2 := \left(   \dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{6},\dfrac{1}{6},-\dfrac{5}{6}   \right) $ .

I verified that these vectors $v_1$,$v_2$ are an orthonormal family.
How can I find $v_3$,$v_4$?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go about this.

One is eyeball the two vectors that you have, pick a pair of linearly independent vectors that are not in their span, and apply the Gram-Schmidt process to them. In this case it’s obvious from inspection that the standard basis vectors $(1,0,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,0,0)^T$ can’t be expressed as linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Another way is to find an orthonormal basis for the *orthogonal complement* of $S=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. *Any* basis for the orthogonal complement will give you a set of vectors that are all orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$, so you just have to make sure that the additional vectors for an orthonormal set by themselves, which can in some cases be less work than the first method. Since the kernel of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of the column space of its transpose, you can find a basis for $S^\perp$ by finding the null space of the matrix that has the given vectors as its *rows*. For this problem, that would be the matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{r}\frac12&\frac12&\frac12&\frac12\\\frac12&\frac16&\frac16&-\frac56\end{array}\right).$$ You can find a basis for the kernel by row-reduction, although that likely won’t give you an orthonormal basis, so you’ll still have to make some adjustments to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that $v_3,v_4$ are not unique. I will compute $v_3$ and leave it to you as an exercise to find $v_4$.

We want to find a nonzero vector $v_3 \in \mathbb R^4 $ with $\langle v_1, v_3 \rangle = \langle v_2, v_3 \rangle = 0$.

I write $v_3 = (a,b,c,d)$. Since $\langle v_1, v_3 \rangle = 0$, I can deduce that $\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}c + \frac{1}{2}d = 0$, i.e $a + b + c + d = 0$. Similarly, taking the scalar product with $v_3$ gives $ a + \frac{1}{3}b + \frac{1}{3}c - \frac{5}{3}d = 0$. So it is easy to see that $v_3 = (0,1,-1,0)$ solves the two previous equations, i.e is orthogonal to $v_1,v_2$. You can normalize it, i.e take $v_3 = (0, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}, 0)$.

Now try to solve the three equations $\langle x, v_i \rangle = 0$ for $i=1,2,3$ and take a vector of norm 1, so you will obtain your basis.